# Typescript mapped types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

It is recommended to use mapped types over explicitly partial types, see
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types

i.e. instead of

```
interface PersonPartial {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}
```

we'd use

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
type PersonPartial = Partial<Person>;
```

Is it possible to map into the other direction, something like

```
type NotPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]!: T[P];
}
type Person = NotPartial<PersonPartial>;
```

as I have a generated that creates partial interfaces, which break my type checking due to duck typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-?` syntax to remove the `?` from a homomorphic  mapped type *(but keep reading)*:

```
interface Person {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}
type Mandatory<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
}
type PersonMandatory = Mandatory<Person>;
```

[Example on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAPwBcyGYUoA5gNxElzPV0gCu5AEbR2AXwJgAngAcUAWTggAJnDBYokgDwAVAHzIAvPg7EA2qmShkAawiSsMZNoC6AWlpPzzsRJkp0UNggCsqq6pKGyCEqahqaAUG67AQANhBgyNIAjHQJOJF4ZJR0AEQAUlgQJaLsaRnSAEy5mDjRYRoFRRClFVU1QA). This is described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers).

**But**, you don't have to, because TypeScript already has it: `Required<T>`. `Required<T>`...

> ...strips `?` modifiers from all properties of `T`, thus making all properties required.

So:

```
interface Person {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}
type RequiredPerson = Required<Person>;
```

[Example on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyxyIcAthAPwBcyGYUoA5gNxElzPV0gCu5AEbR2AXwJgAngAcUAJQgBHPsCgQAJuijZcAXmQLlqjQB4tOgHzsCAGwhhk0gIx1zOZPrxlKdAEQApLAhfUXY7B2kAJjpDFTVNTHdPbwg-QODQoA).

Comment: Do you have any idea where this is documented? I've just laboriously clicked each individual section of the Handbook and searched for `-?` and `- ?`. Doesn't exist in any of them. I find myself frustrated by TypeScript's poor documentation not for the first (second, third, or fourth) time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Docs ?! This is typescript. Real typescript developers read all the PRs (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919) and all the issues (and don't work since this is a full time job). 

Comment: @T.J.Crowder also the what's new section: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Thanks! Now, if I were a different sort of person, I'd delete all my comments and mark yours as "no longer needed," then post a new answer saying "Yes, you can do that with the new `Required<T>` type in TypeScript 2.8." as if I'd known that... ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wops I always forget about that one.. I'll add it to the answer, 10x

Comment: if you hover over any Utility type in editor or Typescript Playground it will show you how it's done @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That how you can deduct syntax

Comment: Did something changed since this answer? Because now in playground I see: `Property 'age' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'Mandatory<Person>'`, but simply add an age property would fix it.

Comment: @CarmineTambascia That error was the point. `age` is required in `RequiredPerson` which was the ask in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html you can see that Typescript provides a lot of Utility Types. So please that the Utility is not there already. You can find `Required` is best suited for your scenario.

If you want to know more I wrote an article about mapped types [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/mastering-typescripts-mapped-types-5fa5700385eb)